# How to generate a embedded url for multiple signers in docusign that works without sending an email

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

Which api and body request i need to send for creating a multiple signers can sign the docuSign without sending them a email , Can i please get the help of the process :

1. onClick of a link we should be able to navigate user to docuSign url and once first signer completes sign then it needs to trigger a mail to second signer using the api requests in the postman

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want the signers to be embedded or do you want them to receive emails?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of ways that you can request signatures via the API:

1. Embedded Signing - URL that you get from API, it expires in 2 minutes. You can use this inside your application for signing. You CANNOT EMAIL this URL!
2. Remote Signing - DocuSign emails the recipient. The link in the email can be used for a few days, it doesn't expire quickly. This URL cannot be embedded in your application.

You can switch from 1 to 2 and back as you need. You can have different recipients use different signing. It's fully flexible and up to you the developer how to use these. Just as long as you know how to do 1 or 2.

You indicated you are using the Apex Toolkit so here are code examples:

1. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/embedded-sending-signing/
2. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/send-envelope/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the example shared in salesforce is also of signing a single signer into the document, It would be more helpful if you could add multiple signers flow with routing order in the postman and share if it works

Comment: Sure, we have such examples, not for salesforce, but using the eSignature API

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/